# Azure Node Web App - Accessing Logging Data

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-table-storage

How do you do "console.log()" in a NodeJS site deployed to Azure, and actually access the logs without just dumping to blob storage? We've tried several methods, but can't find a method that makes it easy to access the logs.

What we've tried:

**Table Storage**

We've turned on table storage through the portal, and that doesn't pick up anything. With .NET apps we can use TRACE statements and that works fine.

**IISNode/Kudu**

We've configured a iisnode.yml file with the following,

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\5.3.0\node.exe"
loggingEnabled: true
devErrorsEnabled: true
```

And added a rule to our web config file.

```
<rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">  
   <match url="iisnode"/>  
</rule>
```

This seems to dump data to some files in Kudu, accessable from:

https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

Files located at: Home\Application\LogFiles

BUT... how do you access the index.html file, without downloading it??? Even after pulling it.... its incredibly difficult to read through and not very helpful.

So, the Question:

How do you get Node logging configured in Azure, that provides the logs in an easy to read way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, the information level logging will be writed into the files named matching the pattern `*-stdout-*.txt` at the Kudu path `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\` by the function `console.log` on Azure NodeJS WebApp.

You can try to get the json list of the log files in that Kudu path `\LogFiles\Application\` via access the url https://<your_webapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/Application/, and filter the items matching the pattern `*-stdout-*.txt` and get them in programming.

The simple way to read the logs is accessing the url https://<your_webapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/Application/index.html that is the url of `index.html` file in Kudu. Then you can click the log link to browse the log.
[image]

Or you can try to install an extension called `Azure Web Site Logs Browser` via search the word `logs` at the tab `Gallery` on the tab page `Site extensions` of Kudu, then you can read the logs in the `File System - Application Logs` via the url https://<your_webapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/websitelogs/.

[image]

Comment: The second path allows us to see the Kudu logs, which is a big help. Looks like there isn't a way to get Node to log directly to Table Storage, without a logging module like Bunyan. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried enabling diagnostic log for your nodejs app?

[Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/)

To view log without downloading it, have you tried log stream?

[Diagnostic Log Stream](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Diagnostic-Log-Stream)